# What is this knot?

Tags: knots, ropes

My 6 year old daughter was playing with ropes today and tied a knot of her own creation. I tried to demonstrate to her the importance of learning to tie good knots that don't slip, but when I went to yank on her knot, it didn't slip at all. Upon further inspection I concluded that it appears to be a rather sound friction knot. The more force you put on the rope, the tighter the choke on the tail end. After looking at it long enough I started to wonder if I've perhaps seen this knot before in ABOK.

Does anyone recognize this as an established knot?

[image: Knot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be an [Anchor Bend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_bend), which Wikipedia lists as being #1723, #1841 in ABoK.

[image]
(Anchor Bend knot, [Public Domain from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_bend#/media/File:Roringstek.jpg))

---

I found it by initially thinking the knot in your picture looked a little like a round turn with two half hitches, but with only one half hitch, and it being through the wrong place.  [That page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_turn_and_two_half-hitches) on Wikipedia though led me to the [List of hitch knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hitch_knots), and happily one matching your daughter's knot was very close to the top!

It even goes on to say:

> The knot is very similar to a round turn and two half hitches except that the first half hitch is passed under the turn.

thus validating my initial hunch!

Comment: It's normally known as the anchor hitch, by virtue of being a hitch not a bend. Though it does come up listed as a bend on occasion.

Comment: @Separatrix - The wikipedia page notes that too: _"The name is a misnomer, as it is technically not a bend, but a hitch."_